# HangMan Game - The game ends directly after entering the desired word

Tags: java, class, object

This is my code I have written, but when I run it, it does not give me the occasion to play the game.
It should work like a Hangman game.

This is the class code.

```
package assignment2q4;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Assignment2Q4 
{
    private final ArrayList<Character> guessList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final char[] charArray;
    private final String secretWord;
    private int guesses;

    public Assignment2Q4(String word)
    {
        guesses = 0;
        secretWord = word;
        charArray = secretWord.toCharArray();
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

    public void makeGuess(char c)
    {
        guessList.add(c);
        guesses += 1;
    }

    public int getGuessCount()
    {
        return guesses;
    }

    public String getSecretWord()
    {
        return secretWord;
    }

    public String getDisguisedWord()
    {
        char[] disguisedWord = new char[secretWord.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
            disguisedWord[i] = '?';
        String aWord = "";
        char c;
        for(int i = 0; i < guessList.size(); i++)
        {
            c = guessList.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++)
            {
                if(c == charArray[j])
                    disguisedWord[j] = c;
            }
        }
        for(int i =0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
            if(disguisedWord[i] == ' ')
                disguisedWord[i] = '?';
        for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
            aWord = aWord + disguisedWord[i];
        return aWord;
    }

    public boolean isFound()
    {
        boolean correct = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < guessList.size(); i++)
            if(guessList.get(i) != charArray[i])
                correct = false;

        return correct;
    }

}
```

This is my program code.

```
package assignment2q4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String answer = " ", hiddenWord = " ";
    String guess;
    Scanner keyboard;
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the secret word: ");
    answer = keyboard.next();

    Assignment2Q4 hangman = new Assignment2Q4(answer);

    while(!hangman.isFound())
    {
        System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");
        guess = keyboard.next();

        hangman.makeGuess(guess);

        hiddenWord = hangman.getDisguisedWord();
        System.out.println(hiddenWord);
        }
    }
}
```

The output just says :

> "Enter secret word."

Then I enter a word and the program says it was successfully run without giving me the chance to play.

Comment: How do you intend it to work anyway?

Comment: Please specify the output

Comment: What I want the program to do is play a game of Hangman.

Comment: It should take a input from the user, (any word) then it should give back the same word but with ? on certain characters. The user then should guess the word by entering a letter that fits in the word. When the user enters correctly the letter is added. And so on. Otherwise must I add my own list of words to the class and then make the program randomly select a word for the user to try?

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at your main condition-loop :

```
public boolean isFound()
{
    boolean correct = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < guessList.size(); i++)
        if(guessList.get(i) != charArray[i])
            correct = false;

    return correct;
}
```

Look at `guessList.size();` when you load your class for the first time, you have no guesses loaded up. Meaning that your size is effectively `0`.

Let's go back to your mainloop :

```
Assignment2Q4 hangman = new Assignment2Q4(answer);

    while(!hangman.isFound())
```

**Oops !** `while(!hangman.isFound())` is `false` with an empty guesses-list. You never enter your loop at all !

You need to either rethink your `isFound()`  to work with an empty list, or you need to use in your main loop a `do ... while()` like so :

```
do
    {
        System.out.println("Guess a letter: ");
        guess = keyboard.next();

        hangman.makeGuess(guess);

        hiddenWord = hangman.getDisguisedWord();
        System.out.println(hiddenWord);
        }
    } while(!hangman.isFound())
```

Good luck !

Comment: An alternative would be to start with the assumption that correct is false, and only if all the letters are exposed, correct is true. well written answer by the way

Comment: Thanks @Joeblade, you made a good point with that alternative